# Empty response when trying to send email using nodemailer package with an express server

Tags: javascript, express, promise, nodemailer

I can't understand what could be causing the following error in browser:
net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

TypeError: Failed to fetch

I''ll provide a link to the github repo: [NodemailerUser Repository](https://github.com/Newbclharri/NodemailerUser)

The fetch api and XMLHttpRequest execution in app.js was working fine. I was hitting the post route, /contact, and sending the information to the express server. However, after adding the sendMail fxn in the server.js file, the fetch request and XML request would show as "pending" in the browser Network tab on the developer tools window.  I'm not sure what the difference is.

I have used the same setup before, but the data sent from frontend to server was a simple string and not an object.  I don't think sending an object should make a difference, but maybe I did something wrong.

I've also done my due diligence to create app password for the gmail accounts I'm using to authorize this application.

**UPDATE**
Update:

Using Postman, I tried to send data to the post route and received the following error:
Error:  Error: queryA ETIMEOUT gmail
at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:dns:213:19) {
errno: undefined,
code: 'EDNS',
syscall: 'queryA',
hostname: 'gmail',
command: 'CONN'
}

Code:

```
//Frontend JS File:
console.log("connected");
const baseUrl = "http://localhost:3000/"
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const nameUser = document.getElementById("name-field");
const email = document.querySelector("#user-email");
const subject = document.querySelector("#subject-email");
const message = document.querySelector("#message-email");
const button = document.getElementById("send");


form.addEventListener("submit", (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const emailData = {
        nameUser: nameUser.value,
        email: email.value,
        subject: subject.value,
        message: message.value
    
    }
    // sendDataXhrPromise(baseUrl, emailData)
    // .then(console.log("data sent"))
    // .catch(err=>{console.log(err)})

    sendDataAjax(baseUrl, emailData)
});

async function sendDataXhrPromise(url, obj){
    console.log(obj.subject, " submitted :)");
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", url + "contact", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
        xhr.onload = function(){
            console.log("Response Text: ",xhr.responseText, typeof(xhr.responseText), xhr.status, xhr.readyState);
            if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200){                
                alert('Email sent');
                resolve(`resolve ${xhr.response}`);                

            }else{
                alert("Alert: Error");
                reject(`reject: ${xhr.statusText}`);
            }            
        }
        xhr.send( JSON.stringify(obj));
    });        
}

function sendDataAjax(url, obj){
    console.log(obj.subject, " submitted :)");
    if(!obj.message){return};
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/contact",{
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(obj)
    })
        .then(res=>console.log(res))
        .catch(err=>console.log(err));
}

function sendDataXhr(){
    console.log(input.value, " submitted :)");
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", baseUrl + "contact", true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.onload = function(){
            console.log("Status, Response: ", xhr.status, xhr.responseText, xhr.readyState);
            if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200){
                alert('Email sent');

            }else{
                alert("Alert: Error");
            }            
        }
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}

//NodemailerController.js File:

    //////////////////////
// Import Dependencies
//////////////////////
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const path = require("path");

const EMAIL = process.env.EMAIL;
const EMAIL2 = process.env.EMAIL2;
const PASS = process.env.PASS;
const PASS3 = process.env.PASS3;

/////////////////
// Create Router Object
////////////////
const router = express.Router();

//////////
// Routes
//////////

//root:
router.get("/", (req, res)=>{
    const options = {
        root: path.join(__dirname, "../views"),
        dotfiles: "deny",
        headers: {
            "x-timestamp": Date.now(),
            "x-sent": true
        }
    }
    const fileName = "index.html";

    res.sendFile(fileName, options, (err)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else{
            console.log("Sent ", fileName);
        }
    })
});

//contact
router.get("/contact", (req, res)=>{
    const options = {
        root: path.join(__dirname, "../views"),
        dotfiles: "deny",
        headers: {
            'x-timestamp': Date.now(),
            'x-sent': true
        }
    }
    const fileName = "contact.html";

    res.sendFile(fileName, options, (err)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log("Sent ", fileName);
        }
    })
});

router.post("/contact", (req, res)=>{ 
    console.log("req.body: ", req.body)
    const contents = req.body
    if(!contents){
        return res.status(400).send({status: "failed"});
    }  
    sendEmail(contents)
});


//////////////////
// Nodemailer fxns
//////////////////
function sendEmail(obj){
        const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: "gmail",
            auth: {
                user: "test@gmail.com",
                pass: PASS3
            }
        });
        const info = {
            from: "test@gmail.com", // sender address
            to: "test2@gmail.com", // list of receivers
            subject: `Message from ${obj.nameUser} <${obj.email}>: ${obj.subject}`,
            text: obj.message

        };
        transporter.sendMail(info,(err, emailInfo)=>{
            if(err){
                console.log("Error: ", err);
               res.send('error');
            }else{
                console.log('Email sent ' + emailInfo.response);
                res.send('success');
            }
            
        });    
}
module.exports = router;

//server.js File:

///////////////////////
// Import Dependecies
//////////////////////
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const NodemailerRouter = require("./controllers/NodemailerController.js");
const methodOverride = require("method-override");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");


//////////////////////
// Server Application
//////////////////////
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT;

/////////////
//Middleware
/////////////
app.use(morgan("dev")); //log requests to server
app.use(cors());
app.use(methodOverride("__method")); //overide request methods for form submissions
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true})) //parse html form bodies into req.body
app.use(express.json()); //needed to receive data in JSON format from frontend client
app.use("/static", express.static("static")); //serve files via express static route
app.use(NodemailerRouter);

//////////////
// app listener
//////////////
app.listen(PORT, ()=> console.log(`Email servicing on PORT ${PORT}`));
```

Comment: Well your `router.post("/contact", …)` route never sends a response (if there's no error)

Comment: It's not clear what `res` inside of `sendEmail` is. You should be getting an exception from that undeclared variable.

Comment: Good catch!  I totally missed that. However, after removing the instances of undefined res from transport.sendMail, I'm still receiving the same "pending" status and empty post error in the browser console: Developer Tools/Network/Fetch/XML

Comment: Yes, Bergi, correct, the post route isn't sending a response, and I don't know why that is.

Comment: Update:

using Postman I tried to send data to the post route and received the following error:
Error:  Error: queryA ETIMEOUT gmail
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:dns:213:19) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'EDNS',
  syscall: 'queryA',
  hostname: 'gmail',
  command: 'CONN'
}

Comment: "*the post route isn't sending a response, and I don't know why that is.*" - because there's no code that would send a response!

Comment: There is code that would send a response: res.status inside of the conditional block; however, the conditional is never entered as req.body is logged as an empty object and not undefined.

Furthermore, refrain from pretentious comments if you have nothing useful to add.  Don't waist people's time.  There seemed to be an issue with the middleware usage upon further inspection.  The form data was not being parsed before hitting the post route.  Now this is no longer an issue.  the console is logging the correct data from the form post.  The next step will be to test the nodemailer service.

Comment: "*res.status inside of the conditional block; however, the conditional is never entered*" - that's what I wrote in my first comment, unless there is an error where the client sent no content, the server does not send a response in the "happy path" that calls `sendEmail`. If that is actually working, please [edit] your question to include the actual code instead of wasting the community's time by having us point out bugs that turn out not to exist.